# Sorted Combobox

Tags: winforms, sorting, data-binding, combobox

I am using a databinding with a combobx to show my objects in a drop down list. The combo box needs to sort the data within it automatically in alphabetical order after databinding.  How can this be done?  I would like the logic to be generic and applied to the combo box directly, and not on the objects being bound to it.

Comment: My binding data source can be a List<> of anything, since this control will be called from various places with different data.  I tried implementing the OnDataSourceChanged() method and sort the datasource using reflection and the display field, but since I don't really know what the datasource is I didn't manage to find a generic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A databound combobox cannot be sorted directly.  You have to sort the underlying datasource.  This is from MSDN:

```
Attempting to set the Sorted property on a data-bound control raises an
ArgumentException. You must sort the data using the underlying data model.
```

So you might be able to use a SortedList as a binding source.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, it is working fine with me. Only change the names of controls

```
private void sellingTableDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     if (sellingTableDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5) {
         mainItemsDataBindingSource.Sort = "ItemCodeID";
     }
}
```